# Read or Write attributes a XML as embed resource in WPF project

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I want to embed a XML into WPF project in way that on requirement I can update the any attribute in the XML. Sample XML is

```
<Auth uid="" tid="" ac="" sa="" ver="" txn="" lk="">
     <Uses pi="" pa="" pfa="" bio="" bt="" pin="" otp=""/>
     <Tkn type="" value=""/>
     <Meta udc="" fdc="" idc="" pip="" lot="G|P" lov=""/>
     <Skey ci="" ki="">encrypted and encoded session key</Skey>
     <Data type="X|P">encrypted PID block</Data>
     <Hmac>SHA-256 Hash of Pid block, encrypted and then encoded</Hmac>
     <Signature>Digital signature of AUA</Signature>
</Auth>
```

Process to become a XML as embedded resource, and how can I access any attribute of XML and update it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you research that? I am sure there are plenty of resources on how to do it

Comment: Yes I did that but as I am new to WPF don't understand properly. In most of the references giving the reading of the XML while firstly I have to create this schema as embedded resource. Please guide me.

Comment: so you are saying that you looked up "_How to read xml in c# wpf_" and you did not get anything usefull or clear?

Comment: Not I doesn't mean that I am I asking after creating this XML schema how can I update the specific attributes of XML.

Comment: Use XmlSerializer.  It will input the xml into the class the xml schema will generate.